# Who is Kimihiro Watanuki?

Tags: xxxholic

In xxxHolic, Watanuki is stated as being Tsubasa (Syaoran) Li's alternate existence. What does that mean? How does that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this page](http://tsubasa.wikia.com/wiki/Kimihiro_Watanuki)

> He [Watanuki] was born when Syaoran made his wish of rewinding time, in order to fill his void left to his parents.<sup>1</sup> Thus he became Syaoran and Sakura's son, but they made a wish for him to be different to "Syaoran Li" otherwise he would cease to exist.

And according to [this page](http://tsubasa.wikia.com/wiki/Syaoran_Li), it was confirmed by a fortune teller in xxxHolic.<sup>2</sup>

---

[This page](http://tsubasa.wikia.com/wiki/Tsubasa_Li) states that

> Watanuki is created to 'replace' Syaoran as the son of Sakura and Syaoran Li.

---

And it also states that he

> was "born" to replace the void in the relationships Syaoran had made.

---

Also, [this other page](http://xxxholic.wikia.com/wiki/Kimihiro_Watanuki) says that

> Watanuki was in fact created out of a space time distortion to replace Tsubasa Syaoran as the son of the reincarnated clones

---

And, lastly, [this other page](http://xxxholic.wikia.com/wiki/Syaoran_%28Tsubasa%3a_Reservoir_Chronicle%29) states

> The connection between Syaoran and Watanuki is finally revealed in the Clow's future arc. Syaoran explains to the party what happened when he met Sakura (the real Princess of Clow). After he had made a wish to turn back time in order to grab Sakura's hand and save her from dying, Watanuki was born to take his place in his world. Fei Wong explains to him that "he's not a brother, he is you". And since he was a being not originally meant to be, he continues to tell him that his existence would cause only pain to those around him.

---

I believe this answers your question, but I am not sure, since I do not see either shows or mangas.

---

---

<sup>1</sup> *Tsubasa:Reservoir Chronicles*, Chapter 201
<sup>2</sup> *xxxHolic*, Chapter 170